# How do I return an input tag from a function?

Tags: reactjs

I have a button on my webpage, and I want an input tag to appear, whenever the user clicks that button. I earlier tried something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [showInput, setShowInput] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setShowInput(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
      {showInput ? <input type="text" /> : ""}
    </div>
  );
}
```

But this only worked once. I want it to add an input tag whenever the user clicks that button. How do I do so?

Comment: You want to be able to hide the input element?

Comment: hide? No? Don't go over my code, I have just put it there so that I can show you guys, how I approached this problem. I just want a button that adds an input tag, whenever the user clicks it

Comment: Oh ok and i assume you also want the input elements to be controlled components?

Comment: What do you mean by controlled components? @Yousaf

Comment: [React - Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of maintaining the number of input elements in the state, i suggest that you maintain an object in the state that is initially empty. Once the button is clicked to add an input, you could update the object with a key-value pair that represents the new `input` element.

State after adding one input could like as shown below:

```
{ 
   input1: { value: '' }
}
```

Similarly, as more inputs are added, more objects will be added in the state.

This will allow your input elements to be [`controlled components`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and will allow you to handle the `onChange` event with only one event handler function.

#### Demo

```js
let counter = 1;

function App() {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = React.useState({});

  const handleClick = () => {
    const inputName = "input" + counter++;
    const inputObj = { value: "" };

    setInputs({ ...inputs, [inputName]: inputObj });
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setInputs({ ...inputs, [name]: { ...inputs[name], value } });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Add Input</button>

      <div className="inputContainer">
        {Object.keys(inputs).map((inputName) => {
          const { value } = inputs[inputName];
          return (
            <input
              key={inputName}
              name={inputName}
              value={value}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder={inputName}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.inputContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

input {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't understand of having an object? like at the starting of your answer, you say that we initialise the state as an empty object. I didn't understand the point of it.

Comment: Inputs will be rendered based on the key-value pairs in the object saved in the state. Each key-value pair in the object represents a single input element where name of the input is the key and value is another object which contains data related to the input like its value, its placeholder text etc.

Comment: Okay, but can't I have a counter variable and then loop over it , and print my input tag. I mean, I am just saying. It is another way to approach this problem. Is there any major difference between these two methods? @Yousaf

Comment: That will render the inputs but how will you access the value of the each input element? If each input is a controlled component, then you can easily access the value of each input because its already saved in the state.

Comment: Okay, I understood upto the handleClick method, but what does handleChange does? I couldn't understand that. @Yousaf

Comment: It destructures the `name` and `value` properties from the `event.target` object and then updates the state by using the `name` property of the input which triggered the `onChange` event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222354/discussion-between-maybenextt1me-and-yousaf).

Comment: Could you please come to the discussion room, I have some questions to ask

Answer (score 1):

Make `showInput` a **number** that defaults to `0`.

Have `handleClick` **increment** that number instead of just setting `true`.

Outside the return expression, create an array. With a `for` loop, push inputs (until you reach the number specified) into the array.

Replace the line where you add the input to the JSX with that array.

Comment: Note OP, with dynamic arrays it's good for them to have unique keys, so React can properly identify them all. That way there's no issues with adding/removing them. You can Google about React array of elements and unique keys for more info

Answer (score 1):

Something like ...

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([]);
  const handleClick = () => setInputs([...inputs, ""]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
      {inputs.map(i => <input type="text"/>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now you can also store your input values into your `inputs` state for further processing.

I leave formatting up to you ... !

Comment: If inputs state has a default value of an empty array, then what's the point of spreading it into SetInputs and then adding an empty string? @Cedric Druck

Comment: Read the question, I guess

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const initialValue = [{ value: "first input" }];

  const [userInputs, setUserInputs] = useState(initialValue);
  const handleClick = () => {
    const updatedInputs = [...userInputs, { value: "new input"}]
    setUserInputs(updatedInputs);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
      {userInputs.map((el, i) => (
        <input type="text" value={el.value} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the implementation above is correct, But I also have my own implementation.

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [showInputs, setInputs] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setInputs((prev) => {
      const i = prev.length + 1;
      return [
        ...prev,
        <Fragment key={i}>
          <input type="text" />
          <br />
        </Fragment>
      ];
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
      <br />
      {showInputs}
    </div>
  );
}
```